# Redefinition of 'class Sleep'

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Qt 5.7

> ```
> error: redefinition of 'class Sleep'
>  class Sleep: public QThread {
>        ^
> ```

```
#ifndef TASKTRED_H
#define TASKTRED_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QObject>

class TaskThred : public QThread
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  TaskThred(QObject *parent = 0):
      QThread(parent)
  {}

  void run();
  int interval;
  int id;

signals:
  void timeIsNow(int);


};

class Sleep: public QThread { // ОШИБКА ЗДЕСЬ
public:
    static void msleep(int ms)
    {
        QThread::msleep(ms);
    }
};

#endif // TASKTRED_H
```

Comment: а просто msleep(ms); не работает? Без QThread::?

Comment: static void msleep(int ms)
    {
        msleep(ms);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать другое имя вместо `Sleep` (или внести его в пространство имен). Компилятор фразой:

> `redefinition of 'class Sleep'`

явно говорит, что такое имя уже где-то используется. Например, это может быть WinAPI функция [`Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: перенёс в отдельный файл, всё заработало.

Comment: @shaman888 в отдельный от `TaskThred`?

Comment: нет, в отдельный *.h поместил класс Sleep

Comment: @shaman888 в таком случае возможно проблема проявится позже. При использовании класса `Sleep`.